# Can we launch Word document in background with out showing in front using swift for MacOs

Tags: swift, macos, ms-word, macos-mojave

I want to launch Microsoft Word background without showing windows in front and also not appearing in Dock. I am trying below code

```
 NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.microsoft.Word", options: .withoutActivation, additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil, launchIdentifier:nil )
```

This is from Apple Documentation

```
static var withoutActivation: NSWorkspace.LaunchOptions
```

> Launch the app but do not bring it into the foreground.

I want only pid running corresponding to it and don't want to see any UI related to it